# Bizarre Behavior Calling Constants in Separate Class

Tags: apex, bug

seeing some odd behavior in this code.

I have constants class...there are several constants but I have only included the problem constant for this example.

When I set an `integer varible` to a `constant` declared in Constants Class, it deprecates the value by 1.

Anyone know why this is the behavior? Is it a bug? Seems odd to be a feature...

```
public without sharing class MyConstants{
   public final static Integer DEFAULT_COUNT = 5; 


}

Visual Force Controller....

public with sharing VisualForceController{
    public Integer rowCount = MyConstants.DEFAULT_COUNT; 
    public void addStuff(){
           System.debug('rows = ' + rowCount); // This returns 4 even though the constant is 5 
           System.debug('default rows = ' + MyConstants.DEFAULT_COUNT); // This returns 5. 
}


}
```

[image: Debug Log]

Comment: Make sure you modify the controller class after changing the constant. It is likely the value reference is replaced at compile time, if it is anything like java compilation.

Comment: When you say modify the controller class, what modification are you referring to?

Comment: I suspect the last time you changed the controller class your constant was 4. Just make a comment change and save/deploy the class again.

Comment: My guess would be possibly name shadowing? i.e. you think you're referencing one variable but it's really another? Try this exercise: `addStuff() { Object rowObj = rowCount, constObj = MyConstants.DEFAULT_COUNT; System.assert(rowObj === constObj);` If this assertion fails, you're not referencing the same object.